# Find all integer solutions $a, b, c$ to $ab - bc + ca = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

(1) Are there infinitely many integer solutions $(a, b, c)$ to $ab - bc + ca = 1$?

(2) If so, is there a good method for finding any?

(3) Please give other examples if possible.

For example; $a = 2, b = 3, c = 5$ is a solution to $ab - bc + ca = 1$ because $2\cdot 3 - 3\cdot 5 + 2\cdot 5 = 1$.

Also $\gcd(a, b, c) = 1$ should be true.

Comment: The $\gcd$ condition must be satisfied if the equation is satisfied. Indeed, any common divisor of $a$, $b$ and $c$, or indeed of any two of those, divides the left hand side of the equation, so it also divides $1$.

Comment: So, can you show us the work you did up to this point (prior to asking on MSE)?  You've asked three questions. So it would be helpful when you edit to include your thoughts, efforts on each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I am looking for positive integer solutions.  We have $$\frac{c^2-1}{b+c}=c-a\,.$$  So, for a fixed integer $c>1$, take a divisor $d>c$ of $c^2-1$ (which exists since $c^2-1>c$).  Then, $$b=d-c\text{ and }a=c-\frac{c^2-1}{d}$$ are positive integers.  This method gives all solutions $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$.  Furthermore, for each $c>1$, there are exactly $$\frac{1}{2}\,\tau\left(c^2-1\right)$$ pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ which satisfy the required condition. (Here, $\tau$ is the divisor-counting function.)

In particular, $(a,b,c)=(1,1,c)$ works for every $c$ (this corresponds to $d=c+1$).  Donald Splutterwit's family of solutions corresponds to $c=2n-1$ with $d=4n$ (thus, $b=d-c=2n+1$ and $a=c-(n-1)=n$).  Another infinite family is when $d=c^2-1$, so that 
$$(a,b,c)=\left(c-1,c^2-c-1,c\right)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

$a = b = 1 \longrightarrow 1 - c + c = 1 \longrightarrow 1=1$

Answer (score 1):

$a=n, b=2n+1 , c=2n-1$ gives an infinite family of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your form is $SL_3 \mathbb Z$ equivalent to $y^2 - zx.$ All solutions to $y^2 - zx = 1$ are given by $y^2 - 1 = zx.$ Meaning $y$ can be anything and then we demand $xz = y^2 - 1$

Yep. In one direction,
$$ a = y, \; \;  b = x+y, \; \;  c = y+z. $$ Backwards
$$ x = b-a, \; \; y = a, \; \; z = c-a.  $$